# Finding files with names matching regex and current date in a script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, date, find

I want to find files from last day in a directory (ie. yesterday: `/daily-2019-11-26/photo-2019-11-26-15-processed.jpg` should match, and `/daily-2019-11-26/photo-2019-11-26-02-processed.jpg` shouldn't).

If I type it in terminal it works as expected

```
find /daily-$(date -d "-1 day" +%F)/photo-$(date -d "-1 day" +%F)-!(0[0-9])-*.jpg

#                                                                 ^ not 00-09 a.m. hours
```

but does not work in a script file when I run it like `bash script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
find /daily-$(date -d "-1 day" +%F)/photo-$(date -d "-1 day" +%F)-!(0[0-9])-*.jpg
```

I'm getting error: `line 2: syntax error near unexpected token '('`

What is wrong?

Eventually I want to run this script with a cron once a day

Comment: Why should the first example match and the second shouldn't?

Comment: @Toto because I want exclude 00-09 hours in filename: photo-2019-11-26-15-processed.jpg was marked with 15 hour, photo-2019-11-26-02-processed.jpg marked as 02 hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm getting error: `line 2: syntax error near unexpected token '('` What is wrong?

Add [`shopt -s extglob`](https://ss64.com/bash/shopt.html) in your `script.sh` file to enable extended pattern matching.

For instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
find /daily-$(date -d "-1 day" +%F)/photo-$(date -d "-1 day" +%F)-!(0[0-9])-*.jpg
```

**Why did it work when you typed it in terminal, but failed in `script.sh`?**

`extglob` was set to `on`, therefore the extended pattern matching part, i.e. `!(0[0-9])`, was interpreted correctly. However, you have to enable it in each `.sh` script file because it's turned off by default.

<sub>Btw. You can type `shopt extglob` in the terminal to check whether `extglob` is `on` or `off`.</sub>

---

### Other considerations:

#### Quoting the Command Substitution's:

Although not entirely necessary given the formatting of the value(s) returned by your `date` commands), consider double-quoting the [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)'s in your `find` command as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
find /daily-"$(date -d "-1 day" +%F)"/photo-"$(date -d "-1 day" +%F)"-!(0[0-9])-*.jpg

#           ^                       ^       ^                       ^
```

#### Using `ls` instead:

You can also get the same result using [`ls`](https://ss64.com/bash/ls.html) instead of [`find`](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html) (given your question `find` doesn't actually seem necessary):

For instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
ls /daily-"$(date -d "-1 day" +%F)"/photo-"$(date -d "-1 day" +%F)"-!(0[0-9])-*.jpg
```

#### Refactoring

Because you're invoking; `date -d "-1 day" +%F` twice you can assign that to a variable then reference it later. Doing it that way only invokes the `date` command once. For instance below we assign yesterdays date to the arbitrarily named variable `yyyy_mm_dd_yesterday`:

- Using `find`:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  shopt -s extglob
  yyyy_mm_dd_yesterday=$(date -d "-1 day" +%F)
  find /daily-"$yyyy_mm_dd_yesterday"/photo-"$yyyy_mm_dd_yesterday"-!(0[0-9])-*.jpg
  ```
- Using `ls`:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  shopt -s extglob
  yyyy_mm_dd_yesterday=$(date -d "-1 day" +%F)
  ls /daily-"$yyyy_mm_dd_yesterday"/photo-"$yyyy_mm_dd_yesterday"-!(0[0-9])-*.jpg
  ```

---

**Additional note:**

The pathname that you are defining in the `script.sh`, i.e. the part that reads `/daily ...`, will need to be a relative to where `script.sh` resides, or an absolute pathname to the directory.

Answer (score -1):

The 'find' is not really necessary, as the bash pattern perform all the work. Consider bash only solution:

```
shopt -s extglob
DD=$(date -d "-1 day" +'%F')
ls /daily-$DD/photo-$DD-!(0[0-9])-*.jpg
```

Or, using standard pattern (no extglob needed) - I'm not this should work, as the question is not clear about the selection rules, and no input is provided for testing.

```
DD=$(date -d "-1 day" +'%F')
ls /daily-$DD/photo-$DD-[12][0-9])-*.jpg
```